# Condensing Excel data with overlapping index/repetitive word occurrence

Tags: database, excel

I have an excel sheet that is formatted like so:
[image: have]

I would like to format it to be something like this:
[image: want]

It is about 40,000 cells of information, so is there any way to do this that isn't manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably use =SUMIF to achieve this, since you appear to have numbers as values.
Create a new sheet, copy column A from your data sheet to your new sheet and remove duplicates. Copy row 1 from your data sheet to your new sheet.
Use this formula in sheet 2 cell B2:

```
=SUMIF(Sheet1!$A:$A;Sheet2!$A2;Sheet1!B:B)
```

Drag the formula to the right, then down.

Answer (score 1):

I am by no means an excel expert, and this is going to be my first answer ever. Take this into account please.

I've checked it and it works.
I've add a command button in Sheet1 (where the original data is), and when clicked this code writes formatted data into Sheet2.

No need to manually remove duplicates!

```
Dim dU1 As Object, cU1 As Variant, iU1 As Long, lrU As Long
Dim MyArray() As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim h As Integer

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

'Get unique indexes
Set dU1 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
lrU = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'number of rows
cU1 = Range("A2:A" & lrU) 'Assuming your data starts in A2
For iU1 = 1 To UBound(cU1, 1)
   dU1(cU1(iU1, 1)) = 1
Next iU1

'Now dU1 contains indexes as unique values (about, absence, etc.)

For i = 0 To dU1.Count - 1 'for each index
    ReDim MyArray(1 To 1) As Variant 'starts a "new" array

    For j = 2 To 9 'each of the columns with values (D1-D8)
        a = 0
        For k = 2 To lrU 'all rows
            If (Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(k, 1).Value = dU1.keys()(i) And Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(k, j).Value <> "") Then
                    MyArray(UBound(MyArray)) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(k, j).Value 'add value to array
                    ReDim Preserve MyArray(1 To UBound(MyArray) + 1) As Variant 'resize array (now is 1 element longer)
                    a = a + 1
            End If
        Next
        If a = 0 Then 'if no value found, add an element to array anyway
                    MyArray(UBound(MyArray)) = "" 'add value to array
                    ReDim Preserve MyArray(1 To UBound(MyArray) + 1) As Variant 'resize array (now is 1 element longer)
        End If
    Next
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i + 2, 1) = dU1.keys()(i) 'write indexes in another sheet

    For h = 2 To UBound(MyArray)
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i + 2, h) = MyArray(h - 1)
    Next
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! Although the first Sumif way worked, this is also another efficient way to do it it seems.  I appreciate the work ^_^

Comment: Just for the record, since you have all data of each item in an array, it is easy to get the average (`AV=Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(MyArray)`), the number of items(`N=Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(MyArray)`), etc.