# Multi conditional statistics (avg, std dev, z-scores) for large data sets in Excel/VBA

Tags: vba, excel, statistics, large-data

I'm looking to calculate statistics for a large data set on *Excel* and encountering some issues due to data set size.

It seems VBA may be the way to go, as copying AVERAGEIF and STDDEV array functions across data this size is causing long calculation times. Appreciate possible solutions or code that could be used here.

**Goals:**

- To calculate statistics (avg, std dev, z-scores) conditional on 2 identifiers (e.g. average of all heights at 01/01/10)
- Able to handle large data sets (100k+ data points)

**Sample Data:**

```
Date    | User ID | Indicator | Data Point
01/01/10| 1       | Height    | 150
01/01/10| 1       | Weight    | 123
01/01/10| 2       | Height    | 146
01/01/10| 2       | Weight    | 123
01/02/10| 1       | Height    | 156
01/02/10| 1       | Weight    | 160
01/02/10| 2       | Height    | 103
01/02/10| 2       | Weight    | 109
```

Edit:

Expected output would ideally be as z-scores for each data point in a new column.
Example: first z-score would be normalized for all heights on 01/01/10 with:

```
(150 - avg) / stdev
```

Comment: How would you want the output?  Please show expected output in the original post.

Comment: If you aren't limited to VBA, I'd recommend using the Pandas library for Python. Combine a pandas dataframe with xlwings and you can easily import / export chunks of huge data into excel spreadsheets.

Comment: Unfortunately limited to VBA in this case. Something to look into for the future though perhaps.

Comment: Out of time right now for tipping the code, but take a look to [this response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35715923/condensing-excel-data-with-overlapping-index-repetitive-word-occurrence/35727310#35727310) and its comment. Basically that code i) get unique indexes (`Date` and `Indicator` in your case) and ii) built an array with the data. Then you can iii) get the average, etc. of the array.

Comment: What I meant was you are basically creating a three dimensional array, when it is all over what is the end display, are we getting all number for all the heights and weights for a specific user id?  Or are we getting all the numbers for all the user ids for a specific indicator?  Or are we getting them all for everything?  If so how do you want the grid to look when it is finished?  Too many questions,  But as @CMArg has stated you could write a UDF that returns and array that you then could use in your formulas.

Comment: @ScottCraner I believe the User ID is largely unimportant this stage as none of the statistics are calculated around it (rather, it will be used for analysis at a later stage). The goal here would be to get a z-score (derived from the data point and the relation to other data points of the same date and same indicator) for every data point. As mentioned, it's indeed possible via functions like averageifs. As an example for 1st data point of 150 '=AVERAGEIFS(D:D,A:A,A2,C:C,C2)'

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is a z-score, since I'm getting same (+/-) value for all data points. But I'm confident that you will be able to modify the code to get what you want.
Data is supposed to be located in sheet "Data", in which there is a command button named Go for the code to execute.
Beware! Code is clearing all content from column E onwards.

```
    Dim lLastRowDB As Long
    Dim dU1 As Object, cU1 As Variant, iU1 As Long, lrU As Long
    Dim dU2 As Object, cU2 As Variant, iU2 As Long
    Dim MyArray() As Variant
    Dim lAV As Double
    Dim lSD As Double
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim k As Integer

    Private Sub Go_Click()
    Worksheets("Data").Columns("E:EZ").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft 'Clear previous results
    lLastRowDB = Worksheets("Data").Cells(2, 1).End(xlDown).Row 'Assuming your data starts in A2

    'Indexes from Column1 (Dates)
    Set dU1 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    lrU = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    cU1 = Range("A2:A" & lrU)
    For iU1 = 1 To UBound(cU1, 1)
      dU1(cU1(iU1, 1)) = 1
    Next iU1

    'Indexes from Column3 (Indicators)
    Set dU2 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    cU2 = Range("C2:C" & lrU)
    j = 0
    For iU2 = 1 To UBound(cU2, 1)
      dU2(cU2(iU2, 1)) = 1
    Next iU2

    'If want to see values in dictionaries, uncomment following six lines

    'For i = 0 To dU1.Count - 1
    '    MsgBox "dU1 has " & dU1.Count & " elements and key#" & i & " is " & dU1.Keys()(i)
    'Next
    'For i = 0 To dU2.Count - 1
    '    MsgBox "dU2 has " & dU2.Count & " elements and key#" & i & " is " & dU2.Keys()(i)
    'Next

    'The following code will look in the complete set of data for each index
    'This accounts for unsorted data, but is resourse-consuming
    'If your data is ordered for shure, just loop the desired rows

    For i = 0 To dU1.Count - 1 'for each Date
        For j = 0 To dU2.Count - 1 'for each Indicator
            ReDim MyArray(1 To 1) As Variant 'reset the array
            For k = 2 To lLastRowDB 'Scan all rows
                If (Worksheets("Data").Cells(k, 1).Value = dU1.keys()(i)) Then
                    If (Worksheets("Data").Cells(k, 3).Value = dU2.keys()(j)) Then
                        MyArray(UBound(MyArray)) = Worksheets("Data").Cells(k, 4).Value 'add found value to array
                        ReDim Preserve MyArray(1 To UBound(MyArray) + 1) As Variant 'now array is 1 element longer
                    End If
                End If
            Next
            'Now MyArray contains desired data.
            'Get average and SD
            lAV = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(MyArray)
            lSD = Application.WorksheetFunction.StDev(MyArray)
             'Titles
             Worksheets("Data").Cells(1, 5) = "Average"
             Worksheets("Data").Cells(1, 6) = "SD"
             Worksheets("Data").Cells(1, 7) = "z-scores"

            For k = 2 To lLastRowDB
                If (Worksheets("Data").Cells(k, 1).Value = dU1.keys()(i)) Then
                    If (Worksheets("Data").Cells(k, 3).Value = dU2.keys()(j)) Then
                        Worksheets("Data").Cells(k, 5) = lAV
                        Worksheets("Data").Cells(k, 6) = lSD
                        If lSD = 0 Then
                            Worksheets("Data").Cells(k, 7) = "SD is zero. Unable to calculate z-scores"
                        Else
                            Worksheets("Data").Cells(k, 7) = (Worksheets("Data").Cells(k, 4).Value - lAV) / lSD 'z-scores
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        Next
    Next

    End Sub
```