# Looping over each vba collection failing conflicting variable types

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VBA and am picking up pieces. I'm having a problem understanding the collection created and then looping over it to read the values against each key one at a time. My code is below.

Excel Data I'm using with the data

[image: Source Data]

Suffice to say, the error I get in Excel 2016 when running the module is:
[image: ErrorwWhen running the module]

Pressing Debug shows
[image: Doesn't like dataItems]

I'm trying to print the values against the keys. I expected 80, 20 etc.. to be printed. Could someone please help me to understand why I'm wrong in writing dataItems and how to resolve so it prints the values agains the keys - I suspect it's a for loop that's needed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Code I'm using:

Class : CItems

```
Option Explicit

Public Key As String
Public Sum As Long
Public Count As Long
Public ItemList As Collection
Public Function Mean() As Double
    Mean = Sum / Count
End Function
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Sum = 0
    Count = 0
    Set ItemList = New Collection
End Sub
```

Module: m_Call

```
Option Explicit

Sub m_Call()

''' Create Collection from Column A and B in worksheet called RAW_DATA

Dim col As Collection
Dim dataItems As cItems
Dim itemKey As String
Dim item1 As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim r As Long

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RAW_DATA")
Set col = New Collection

For r = 2 To 3000
    itemKey = CStr(ws.Cells(r, "A").Value2) '~~adjust to your own column(s)
    item1 = CLng(ws.Cells(r, "B").Value2) '~~adjust to your own column(s)

    'Check if key already exists
    Set dataItems = Nothing: On Error Resume Next
    Set dataItems = col(itemKey): On Error GoTo 0

    'If key doesn't exist, create a new class object
    If dataItems Is Nothing Then
        Set dataItems = New cItems
        dataItems.Key = itemKey
        col.Add dataItems, itemKey
    End If

    'Add cell values to the class object
    With dataItems
        .Sum = .Sum + item1
        .Count = .Count + 1
        .ItemList.Add item1
    End With

Next

'Iterating through all of the items
Dim i As Long
i = 5
For Each dataItems In col

    Debug.Print dataItems.Mean
    ws.Cells(5, i) = dataItems.Key
    ' read in column 5 and check search each cells content to see if it matches a collection key's string.
    i = i + 1
Next

'Selecting one item
'Set dataItems = col("PersonA 1")


'ws.Cells(4, 5) = dataItems.Mean


''' Read excel and populate categories if the value in a column A cell matches with a key in the Collection.
''' Column 10 and 11 should have the values that match each Key inserted respectively.

    Dim cols As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim currentRow As Long
    Dim category As Variant



    ' Use a  With block to 'Fully Qualify' the ranges to MySheet
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RAW_DATA")
        ' Set col range to the intersection of used range and column B
        Set cols = Intersect(.UsedRange, .Columns("A"))
        ' Loop through cells in cols to set description in each row
        For Each rng In cols
            currentRow = rng.Row
            ' Read in key's from collection
            For Each dataItems In col
                ' read in column and search each cells content to see if it matches a collection key's string.
                .Cells(currentRow, 10) = rng.Value
                If rng.Value = dataItems.Key Then
                    .Cells(currentRow, 10) = "Working"
                    'Debug.Print dataItems
                    '''Need to insert value1 from key into Column 10 and value2 from same key into column 11.
                    ''' I'm just testing to see if I can insert a single category first before working on the loop.
                    .Cells(currentRow, 10) = "Shopping"
                    .Cells(currentRow, 11) = dataItems
                End If
            Next

        Next rng
    End With

''' End of Read excel

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you looked at using `Scripting.Dictionary`?

Comment: Not sure what that is. I tried a dictionary entry but when I ran it it said something like object undefined. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I really cannot get what you want to achieve. Also, I have the vague idea that you are overthinking your problem. With those concerns in mind, try the following and see if it helps you.

```
If rng.Value = dataItems.Key Then
    .Cells(currentRow, 10) = "Working"
    'Debug.Print dataItems
    '''Need to insert value1 from key into Column 10 and value2 from same key into column 11.
    ''' I'm just testing to see if I can insert a single category first before working on the loop.
    .Cells(currentRow, 10) = "Shopping"
    For k = 1 To dataItems.Count
        .Cells(currentRow, k + 11) = dataItems.ItemList(k)
    Next
End If
```

Also, try to use the Watch Window, adding `dataItems` as the inspected variable. Insert a Breakpoint in your code (for example in `If rng.Value = dataItems.Key Then`), and step on with F8.

Comment: You might want to check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35774530/1726522). I'm not sure, but might be similar to your problem.